# Django execute order by before filter

Tags: python, django, web, filter, django-queryset

i'm using django 2.0.7
so, i want to order a queryset and then select distinct entries,
after that, i'm gonna perform some filtering 
as you can see here i'm doing the order and select distinct stuff

```
forms = Form.objects.order_by('user','-created_at').distinct('user')
```

and here i'm filtering some attributes

```
filterd_qs = forms.filter(**query)
```

**the problem is that the order_by query is executed after the filter query** which causes unexpected results (it's applying the filter on the whole queryset),
the sql query resulted from the last filter :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("table"."user_id") fields FROM "appname_form" WHERE where_clause ORDER BY "appname_form"."user_id" ASC, "appname_form"."created_at" DESC;
```

so how do i force django orm to wrappe the orderby query by the filter query !!
any suggestion will do

**edit:** guys i think you didnt understand the problem,
let's say that we have this queryset

```
queryset = [
('john',"02-23-2020",type2),
('sarah',"02-03-2020",type1),
('joe',"01-11-2020",type2),
('john',"02-25-2020",type1),
('joe',"02-28-2020",type1)
]
```

when i first do the distinct orderby query the result will be

```
queryset = [
('john',"02-25-2020",type1),
('sarah',"02-03-2020",type1),
('joe',"02-28-2020",type1)
]
```

and then, when i execute the filter for example:

```
queryset = Form.objects.order_by('user','-created_at').distinct('user')
qs = queryset.filter(type=type2)
```

the result will be

```
queryset = [
('john',"02-23-2020",type2),
('joe',"01-11-2020",type2)
]
```

although the result should an empty queryset !!

Comment: Well you should use `Form.objects.filter(..).order_by(..).distinct(..)`. Exactly why is that a problem?

Comment: That's the syntax for SQL, ORDER BY always comes after WHERE

Comment: the problem is that i need to narrow down the results to be one for each user, and then perform the filter **on that result**, but what's actually happening is that the filter is performed on all the rows !!

Comment: yes i know that this the syntax of SQL, that's why i said if there is any way to force django ORM to ** wrappe the last result (perform another select on the ordered query)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a subquery which contains the latest `Form` per user and then filter by this subquery to get what you want

```
forms = Form.objects.filter(
    id__in=Form.objects.order_by('user','-created_at').distinct('user').values('id')
).filter(**query)
```

MySQL is usually pretty bad at processing subqueries, it may perform better if you evaluate the subquery and pass the result if you're using MySQL. PostgreSQL is much better at handling subqueries and should be fine

Comment: thaaaaanx a loot, that was it :)

Comment: i'm using postgres, so i should be fine then ;)